# Rewrite rules are chosen inconsistently

Tags: rewrite-rules, plugin-polylang

I am trying to get some rewrite rules working with Polylang and I'm using the Rewrite Rules Inspector plugin to inspect the rules. Different rules are applying in different environment: my local environment versus my development site.

The first screenshot is from my local. The first rule in the top of the list (highlighted) is what is respected:

[image: local rewrite rules]

The second screenshot is from my development site. The exact same rules match, except instead of using the rule at the top of the list, it decides to use the rule second from the bottom (highlighted), which does not set the `paged` query variable.

[image: dev site rewrite rules]

Why would WordPress decide the use the rule in the second screenshot, instead of the rule in the first screenshot, when both rules apply but the first should take priority? Both environments are using WordPress 6.3 with the exact same plugins.

Shouldn't the rule at the top of the list here always take precedence?

Comment: WP always uses the first rule that matches, it doesn't discern so the order the rules are registered in is significant. What you're asking for implies the code is not the same, or the plugins aren't the same, or code paths are not the same on each environment